# Bootstrap - dropdown menu not working?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My dropdown menu in Bootstrap doesnt appear to be working - can anyone alert me to the problem? Right now it displays the dropdown, but clicking it does nothing. Thanks!

JS:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container" style="width: auto;">

            <a class="brand" style="text-indent: 3em" href="#">
                Title
            </a>

            <ul class="nav">
                <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Statistics</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Reader</a></li>

                <li class="dropdown" id="menu1">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#menu1">
                    Options
                    <b class="caret"></b>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

            </ul>


        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: And what is the expected behavior when clicked? I don't understand your question.

Comment: It should just make a simple dropdown menu, a button when clicked that brings down more options. I followed the bootstrap guide online almost to a Q, and it still doesn't work. The button will appear, but clicking it will not make a dropdown menu.

Comment: Your code works fine for me, did you forget maybe to include jQuery and the dropdown plugin? Here is a demo of your code working: http://jsfiddle.net/u5vhS/18/   (i overwrote a demo from another question i answered similar to this one)

Comment: Strange... I actually solved the problem, but in a strange way. I had the dropdown plugin in bootstrap/js, and moved it to the generic js folder. Does jquery actually need to be in the same directory as the plugin? That would explain the error... anyway, thanks for your help!

Comment: No, it does not matter where the js scripts lay as long as you reference them correctly in your document.

Comment: Just a comment on theeggman85's solution - I'm not quite sure how I created the problem. But, touching the bootstrap dropdown file sorted it out... I think it might be to do with the inclusion order or somesuch.

Comment: It doesn't work with jQuery 1.6. You need a higher version of jQuery

Comment: I am having same problem when i firebug it, I got an error 

TypeError: $(...).dropdown is not a function

I included the jquery, I check it with my view source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am getting you correctly, when you say that clicking does nothing, do you mean that it does not point to your URL?

In the anchor tag `<a href>`it looks like you did not pass your file path to the `href` attribute. So, replace the **#** with your actual path for the file that you want to link.

```
<li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
<li><a href="action link here">Another action</a></li>
<li><a href="something else link here">Something else here</a></li>
<li class="divider"></li>
<li><a href="seperated link here">Separated link</a></li>
```

I hope this helps with your issue.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your comment! What I meant was that the dropdown menu isnt even appearing, the button to bring it down is on the page but clicking it will not drop down the menu. I figure something must be wrong with my jquery, any idea?

Comment: could you please send me your page link in message? i will take a look at it, ir if ya want i will show you a more easier way with JQuery for a dropdown menu

Comment: he hasnt even answered your question correctly how come this be the right answer? This is misleading. @theeggman85

Answer (score 115):

Check if you're referencing `jquery.js` **BEFORE** `bootstrap.js` **and** `bootstrap.js` is loaded **only once**. That fixed the same error for me:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: same issue here when referencing bootstrap twice.

Comment: got error, but switched to  
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.0.js"></script>
then working as well.. so weird

Answer (score 10):

This is a Rails specific answer, but I had this same problem with Bootstrap dropdown menus in my Rails app. What fixed it was adding this to app/assets/javascripts/application.js:

//= require bootstrap

Hope that helps someone.

Answer (score 8):

putting

```
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

file at the last after the

```
<script src="jq/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>  solved this problem for me .
```

this is how i use write it now and no problem

```
<script src="jq/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 4):

I've scratched my head for the last few hours and only figured it is due to difference between bs4 and bs5, namely you should replace data-toggle="dropdown"  in bs4 with data-bs-toggle="dropdown" in bs5 and vice versa, hope that helps

Answer (score 2):

Double importing jquery can cause Error

`<script src="static/public/js/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>`

OR

`<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

Answer (score 1):

I had to download the source files instead of just the compressed files that it says to use for quick start on the bootstrap website

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. The version of bootstrap.js that visual studio seems to be hosed. I just pointed to this URL instead:

```
    <link id="active_style" rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.1.1/cosmo/bootstrap.min.css">
```

For completeness, here's the HTML and javascript

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li id="theme_selector" class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Theme <b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul id="theme" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Amelia</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Cerulean</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Cyborg</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Cosmo</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Darkly</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Flatly</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Lumen</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Simplex</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Slate</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Spacelab</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Superhero</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">United</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Yeti</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
```

Javascript

```
$('#theme li').click(function () {
        //alert('item: ' + $(this).text());
        switch_style($(this).text());
    });
```

Hope it helps someone

Answer (score 0):

you are missing the "btn btn-navbar" section. For example:

```
        <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </a>
```

Take a look to navbar documentation in:

[Twitter Bootstrap](http://203rc1.getbootstrap.com/components.html#navbar)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using electron or other chromium frame, you have to include jquery within window explicitly by:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="local_path/jquery.js" onload="window.$ = window.jQuery = module.exports;"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

When i checked i saw **display: none;** value is in the **.dropdown-menu** bootstrap css class. Hence i removed it.

Answer (score 0):

On bootstrap 4.5.0 it stopped working for a few days in Dec. 2023 and it is now back normal

Answer (score -2):

put following code in your page

```
  Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequest);
    function EndRequest(sender, args) {
        if (args.get_error() == undefined) {
        $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's that? Some VB proprietary code ported to C# and used to maintain a 1986 mainframe?