# Bootstrap dropdown links not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the latest version of bootstrap, and I have a top menu page with a fixed top navbar.

It has several links, and a search form. The search submits the query via AJAX and then outputs the results of the php file with a drop down result.

I am able to get the results to post and get the dropdown menu working, but the links are not clickable. They are highlighted and I can see href below in the status bar, but I can't click through.

## HTML CODE:

```
<div class="row">
<img class="img-responsive center-block" src="images/header.jpg">
<!-- Fixed navbar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-rc">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="highlight-light navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#top-navbar">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand visible-xs" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home">&nbsp;</span>Main Menu</a>
        </div>
        <div id="top-navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="highlight-light nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="newcontact.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user">&nbsp;</span>New Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="newsearch.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search">&nbsp;</span>Search</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt">&nbsp;</span>Attendance</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar">&nbsp;</span>Planner</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-stats">&nbsp;</span>Statistics</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" id="QuickSearch" role="form" method="post" action="">
                        <div class="form-group form-group-xs">
                            <input type="text" class="input" placeholder="Search by Name or Email" name="SearchTerm" id="SearchTerm"/>
                            <div class="btn-group btn-group-xs">
                                <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Search" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    <div id="QuickSearchResults"></div>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="newlogout.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out">&nbsp;</span>Log-out</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
</nav>
</div>
```

## JS

```
$("#QuickSearch").submit(function(){

$.blockUI({ message: '<h1><img src="img/busy.gif" />&nbsp;Please Wait...</h1>' }); 
// Intercept the form submission
var formdata = $(this).serialize(); // Serialize all form data

// Post data to your PHP processing script
$.post( "quicksearch.php", formdata, function( data ) {
    // Act upon the data returned, setting it to #success <div>
    $("#QuickSearchResults").html ( data );
    $(function () {
        $('#QuickResultsMenu').dropdown('toggle');
    });
    $.unblockUI();
});

return false; // Prevent the form from actually submitting
});
```

## PHP

```
/* Code that does DB connection and processing, then below */
<ul id="QuickResultsMenu" class="dropdown-menu padding10">
<?php   
//And we display the results 
foreach($ContactSearch as $Results) : ?>

<!-- Search Results -->
    <li class="smalltext">
        <a href="contact.php?Id=<?php echo $Results['Id'];?>"><?php echo $Results['FirstName'];?>
        <?php echo $Results['LastName'];?>,<?php echo $Results['Phone2'];?>,<?php echo $Results['Email'];?></a>
    </li>

<?php endforeach; ?>

<!-- Total Search Results -->
    <li class="">
        <form role="form" id="QuickResults" name="QuickResults">
        Show more results
        </form>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I noticed that if I remove the ul tag that is in the php code, the links work fine, but the styling gets messed up. I can't figure out how to make this look right and be functional. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

## CSS

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

/* START
** Div and container setup */

/* Set a max-width for horizontal fluid layout and make it centered */
.container-fluid {
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    max-width: 970px;
}

/* Padding */
.padding10 {
    padding:10px;
}

/* Shadow for Page Outline */
.rcshadow {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 10px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 10px #000;
    -khtml-box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 10px #000;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 10px #000;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 15px 15px;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 15px 15px;
}

/* Page Outline */
.rcpage {
    background-color:#FFF;
    padding:10px 30px 20px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 15px 15px;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 15px 15px;
}

/* Body */
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-size:100%;
    font-family:verdana,arial,'sans serif';
    background-color:#3b607e;
    color:#000000;
}

/* END
** Div and container setup */


/* START 
** Navbar Styling */
.navbar-rc {
    margin-bottom:0px;
    -moz-border-radius:0px;
    border-radius:0px;
}

.navbar-nav > li > a, .navbar-brand {
    padding-top:5px !important; 
    padding-bottom:0 !important; 
    height: 30px; 
} 

.highlight-light > li:hover, .highlight-light .navbar-brand:hover {
    background-color:#e7e7e7;   
}


.highlight-dark > li:hover {
    background-color:#000000;   
}

.navbar {
    min-height:30px !important;
}
/* END 
** Navbar Styling */


/* START 
** Typography */
h1 {
    font-size:2em;
    color:#739CBF;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-shadow: #000 1px 1px 2px;
    text-align:center;
}

h2 {
    font-size:1.4em;
    color:#3b607e;
    font-weight:bold;
}

h3 {
    font-size:1.4em;
    color:red;
    font-weight:bold;
}

h4 {
    font-size:1.4em;
    color:#000;
    font-weight:bold;
}

/* Used for search text */
.smalltext {
    font-size:xx-small;
    color:#ABABAB;
}

.error {
    color:red;
    font-weight:bold;
}

/* text for footer that goes against background */
.bgtext {
    color: silver;
}

/* Form Error Code */
input.error {
    background: red;
    color: white;
}

/* Form Error Code */
label.error {
    color: red;
}
/* END 
** Typography */

/* START
** Buttons */
.rcbutton {
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #739CBF;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #739CBF;
    box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #739CBF;
    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #87A5BF), color-stop(1, #739CBF) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #87A5BF 5%, #739CBF 100% );
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#79bbff', endColorstr='#378de5');
    background-color:#3B607E;
    -moz-border-radius:6px;
    -webkit-border-radius:6px;
    border-radius:6px;
    border:1px solid #394D5F;
    display:inline-block;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:15px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:6px 24px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 0px #528ecc;
}


.button {
    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #378de5), color-stop(1, #79bbff) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #378de5 5%, #79bbff 100% );
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#378de5', endColorstr='#79bbff');
    background-color:#378de5;
}

.button:hover {
    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #378de5), color-stop(1, #79bbff) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #378de5 5%, #79bbff 100% );
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#378de5', endColorstr='#79bbff');
    background-color:#378de5;
}

.button:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
}
/* END
** Buttons */

/* END
** Miscellaneous */
.panelhead {
    width:420px;
    color:#FFF;
    font-size:1.4em;
    font-weight:bold;
    background-color:#3b607e;
    padding:5px;
    border-top:thick ridge #000;
    border-left:thick ridge #000;
    border-right:thick ridge #000;
}

.panelbody {
    width:420px;
    color:#000;
    font-size:1.1em;
    background-color:#FFF;
    padding:5px;
    border:thick ridge #000;
}

.fullpanelhead {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:890px;
    color:#FFF;
    font-size:1.4em;
    font-weight:bold;
    background-color:#3b607e;
    padding:5px;
    border-top:thick ridge #000;
    border-left:thick ridge #000;
    border-right:thick ridge #000;
}

.fullpanelbody {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:890px;
    color:#000;
    font-size:1.1em;
    background-color:#FFF;
    padding:5px;
    border:thick ridge #000;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}
 .fullpanelsection
{
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:890px;
    position:relative;
}

.fieldcolumn {
    float:left;
    width:180px;
    display:inline;
}

img.pic {
    border:solid thin #000000;
}

img.profilepic {
    border:solid thin #000000;
    display:block;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}

.mousehand {
    cursor:pointer;
}
/* END
** Miscellaneous */

/* START
** PICTURE TAKER */
#videocontainer {
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 500px;
    height: 375px;
}
#videoElement {
    width: 500px;
    height: 375px;
    background-color: #666;
}
#canvas {
    width: 500px;
    height: 375px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    background-color: #CCC;
}
/*
** END PICTURE TAKER */
```

## RENDERED HTML FROM PHP

```
<div class="open" id="QuickSearchResults"><ul aria-expanded="true" id="QuickResultsMenu" class="dropdown-menu padding10">

<!-- Search Results -->
    <li class="smalltext">
        <a href="contact.php?Id=2352">Dave      </a>
    </li>


<!-- Search Results -->
    <li class="smalltext">
        <a href="contact.php?Id=1850">Dave      Fenstermaker</a>
    </li>


<!-- Search Results -->
    <li class="smalltext">
        <a href="contact.php?Id=3268">Dave      Hughes</a>
    </li>


<!-- Search Results -->
    <li class="smalltext">
        <a href="contact.php?Id=24870">Dave     Tello</a>
    </li>


<!-- Search Results -->
    <li class="smalltext">
        <a href="contact.php?Id=18998">Dave     Thigpen</a>
    </li>


<!-- Total Search Results -->
    <li class="">
        <form role="form" id="QuickResults" name="QuickResults">
        Show more results
        </form>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

## Here is a link to a jFiddle demo:

https://jsfiddle.net/v2p04nsa/

Oddly enough, this works. I used the rendered HTML from below in place of the php.

## Head

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Roll Call For Infusionsoft</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="https://avellanenterprises.com/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo "css/bootstrap.min.css" ?>">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo "css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" ?>">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bsmaster.css">
    <script src="<?php echo "js/jquery.min.js" ?>"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo "js/jquery.validate.js" ?>"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo "js/additional-methods.js" ?>"></script>    
    <script src="<?php echo "js/bootstrap.min.js" ?>"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo "js/jquery.blockUI.js" ?>"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: Can you post your css?  Is it vanilla/stock bootstrap of have you edited styles?  More specifically the CSS classes in the UL tag found in the PHP.  I am guessing that is where the problem lies or an uncaught javascript error.  What does your Chrome dev tools console say when you click an href?  Hope this helps.

Comment: Some further reading as well.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9529574/bootstrap-dropdown-menu-not-working

Comment: is that html the rendered html? If not, post the rendered html.

Comment: Have you ensured the correct javascript files are being loaded?

Comment: @redoc - I have posted the CSS above. I am using stock BS and the CSS file I posted above. I don't believe there are any conflicts.

Comment: @Ted - I also posted the rendered html above.

Comment: @JamesR - My Javascript seems to be working fine, as it is posting the results from the php code and doing what was expected.

Comment: No javascript errors in your console?  Just confirming that.   If it works when you remove the UL tag from the php code it point to the "dropdown-menu"and  "padding10" css classes which I would assumed are tightly coupled with the JS in bootstrap.

Comment: @redoc - I have tested a few things now. If I change the ul tag to a div same thing happens. If i removed the classes from the tag same thing. Seems like any tag I put there would cause a problem.

I am not getting any errors in the console, but at this point it has to be the script I would imagine. The way it is triggering seems to be doing something, but looking through the dev menu doesn't show me anything off (at least to my eyes).

Comment: The thing that is tricky about bootstrap is the mingling of JS and css.   Try a couple of things.  1. make sure your jquery is loading first before bootstrap.js.  2. try a different source for jquery and bootstrap.js (if you are loading locally try loading from external link repo and vice-versa).  3. try a different source for bootstrap.css (if you are loading locally try loading from external link repo and vice-versa).  beyond that if you make a plunkr we can debug much more easily.  Happy to help if I can.

Comment: @redoc - I updated my question with a jsFiddle, using all of the code from above (rendered HTML instead of php), and it works there.

Comment: Also, I have jquery before bootstrap, I have changed sources and went from local to CDNs and vice versa for JS and CSS files. Still no change.

Comment: Are you using the following CDNs in your code? https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js  https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css   jquery 1.1.0 onLoad  Please post the head section or lazy load section of your page.   It has to be that if your rendered browser code is working in JSFiddle with the references cited above especially if there are no console errors.  I think you are almost there.

Comment: Yes I am. I have copied the JSfiddle code and made a page with it and the page had the same problem. I used the same loading sequence in the same order. I removed all scripts besides those and still.

I am not sure what the deal is, but I am going to change my approach. I figure I will use modals and put the search results there. Not what I wanted stylistically but I know it would work, and would be more mobile friendly.

Comment: Your jsfiddle is working, please post a non-working jsfiddle to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used a different approach and since have gotten the links working. I had to use a table to output the data and then everything worked fine. I'm not sure why it worked on the JSfiddle but not on a live page. Either way, the tables worked out nicely so no more issues with outputting search results.

### NEW PHP

```
<table class="table table-hover table-condensed">
<thead><tr><th>Full Name</th><th>Mobile Phone</th><th>Email Address</th></tr></thead><tbody>
<?php   

    //And we display the results 
    foreach($ContactSearch as $Results) : ?>
    
    <!-- Search Results -->
    <tr class="clickable-row" onclick="document.location = 'contact.php?Id=<?php echo $Results['Id'];?>';">
    <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user">&nbsp;</span><?php echo $Results['FirstName'];?> <?php echo $Results['LastName'];?></td>
    <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone">&nbsp;</span><?php echo $Results['Phone2'];?></td>
    <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope">&nbsp;</span><?php echo $Results['Email'];?></td></tr>       
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody></table>
```